# CSS condicional al idioma

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css, css3

Cuando se incluye una hoja de estilos CSS, se puede especificar directamente en la etiqueta `link` la *media query* con la condición que debe cumplirse para que se apliquen esos estilos:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 480px)" href="moviles.css" />
```

**¿Existe algo similar pero para el idioma del navegador? ¿o al menos para el caso de texto de derecha a izquierda (ej.: árabe)?** Algo como esto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(lang: ar)" href="rtl.css" />
```

Donde la hoja de estilos sólo contendría cosas como:

```
.flota-izquierda { float: right; }
.float-derecha { float:left; }
.izquierda { text-align: right; }
.derecha { text-align: left; }

....
```

> Sé que podría usar LESS/SASS para simplificar mi código fuente, pero el CSS  generado al compilar seguiría siendo complejo y grande de todos modos, porque al expandirse quedaría como:
>
> ```
> [lang=ar] .flota-izquierda { float: right; }
> [lang=ar] .float-derecha { float:left; }
> [lang=ar] .izquierda { text-align: right; }
> [lang=ar] .derecha { text-align: left; }
>
> ....
> ```

Preferiría una respuesta que sólo usase HTML y CSS, pero si no hay opción, JavaScript también sería una posibilidad a considerar.

Comment: ¿Algo como [**`:lang`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang)?

Comment: Sí, sería algo como `:lang` pero que se pueda aplicar a la hoja de estilos completa y no regla a regla. La idea es no acabar con 1000 reglas a las que añadir `:lang(ar)` al selector

Comment: Puedes minimizar el “impacto” con un [selector mágico](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Comment: @PaulVargas ¿cómo sería? No termino de ver en esa página cómo se haría

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ¿Qué tan recomendable sería utilizar diferentes estilos para diferentes lenguajes? ¿En qué casos es viable hacer esto?

Comment: @Hoose Hay idiomas que van de izquierda a derecha y otros van de derecha a izquierda (por eso mencionaba el caso del árabe en particular): elementos que en un idioma flotan hacia un lado, flotarán hacia el otro en otro idioma o su posición variará entre derecha/izquierda. También algunos colores se asocian con diferentes sentimientos dependiendo de la cultura en la que te encuentres, aunque comprendo que esto no es tan extendido (y no me afecta directamente)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Estas intentando descargar un estilo por idioma/ direccionalidad de texto o descargar todos los estilos y aplicarlos condicionalmente? El resultado no es el mismo de acuerdo a la intención.

Comment: @devconcept sé que con las media queries en el `link` los estilos se descargan aunque no se apliquen. No me importaría que ocurriese eso (porque parece que es el comportamiento por defecto), aunque idealmente se cargarían sólo si lo necesitasen

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Si no te importa el tamaño de la descarga entonces te daré una solución sencilla. Agrega una clase al tag `html` de acuerdo al idioma o la dirección, algo como `<html class="en">` o `<html class="rtl">` y estila apropiadamente. Esta solución es tan sencilla que posiblemente sea la correcta y es algo que he visto hacer muchas veces. Usar `:lang` no lo encuentro apropiado porque puedes tener un usuario que decida ver el sitio en ingles aunque el navegador reporte que su idioma es español. En temas de internalización el usuario tiene la ultima palabra.

Comment: Por la búsqueda que hice online, me parece que por ahí van a ir los tiros. Quería ahorrarme descarga, pero parece que la única opción para ello sería lo que sugiere rnd.

Comment: @devconcept `"... aunque el navegador reporte ..."` Eso no es del todo correcto. Está supeditado al valor del elemento mismo o del valor heredado, de acuerdo al DOM.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Un ejemplo que quizás sea interesante es https://ar.wikipedia.org Usa JavaScript.

Comment: Si tienes que añadir contenido en árabe, ¿por qué no utilizar el aislamiento bidireccional o `bdi`? Te ahorras tener que crear nuevas propiedades para texto en árabe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una forma alternativa que se me ocurre es usando un poco de javascript.

1. Obtienes el valor computado de la propiedad `direction` del `<body>`
2. Agregas el CSS necesario por codigo.

Ejemplo:

```js
// esto obtiene ltr o rtl 
var dir = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).direction
 
// agregamos archivo-ltr.css o archivo-rtl.css
var link = document.createElement( "link" );
link.href = '/ruta/al/archivo-' + dir + '.css';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Esta es, de hecho, una forma correcta de hacerlo. Las [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) no soportan el lenguaje y englobar todo el css en una clase o pseudoclase no evita que este contenido se descargue que es lo que intenta hacer el OP. No incluir el estilo y agregarlo dinámicamente parece ser la solución correcta en este caso.

Comment: En `type` y `rel` tienen comillas dobles al final y comillas simples al principio.

Comment: gracias! corregido

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
p:lang(it) { 
    background: yellow;
}
```

En ese caso pintaría de amarillo el panel cuando el idioma sea Italiano.

Otra forma de hacerlo seria así:

```
/* Ingles (default language)*/
[data-i18n]::before {
   content: attr(data-i18n);
}
/* Aleman */
[data-i18n-de]:lang(de)::before {
   content: attr(data-i18n-de);
}
/* Ruso */
[data-i18n-ru]:lang(ru)::before {
   content: attr(data-i18n-ru);
}
```

Y al declarar el panel indicas el valor que cargaría en cada caso:

```css
/* Ingles (default language)*/

[data-i18n]::before {
  content: attr(data-i18n);
}


/* Aleman */

[data-i18n-de]:lang(de)::before {
  content: attr(data-i18n-de);
}


/* Ruso */

[data-i18n-ru]:lang(ru)::before {
  content: attr(data-i18n-ru);
}
```

```html
<p id="hello" data-18n="Hello" data-i18n-de="Hallo" data-i18n-ru="Привет">.
  <p>
```

Hay otras formas, puedes mirar el siguiente enlace:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/css-driven-internationalization-in-javascript/

Comment: El problema de este método es que si tengo 1000 reglas CSS en la hoja de estilos, tengo que añadir 1000 veces `:lang(it)` que es lo que yo no quiero. ¿Se puede aplicar `:lang(it)` de manera global a toda la hoja de estilos en lugar de regla a relga?

Comment: Agregue información que tal ves te pueda servir

Comment: Esta solución no me vale. He mirado el enlace a Mozilla y no pone nada sobre que se pueda hacer de manera global. Y la edición con los atributos `data-*` para cada idioma acaba teniendo el mismo problema (podría ser útil para contenido, pero no para los estilos).

Comment: Si, creo que es un caso muy específico, en esa liga vienen algunas otras alternativas que probablemente te sirvan

Comment: Y la razon del downvote?

Comment: creo que debería de ser: #hello::before {
  content: attr(data-18n);
} en vez de [data-i18n]::before {
  content: attr(data-i18n);
}